# Gitlab pipeline: Global variable not visible in Job

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have the following `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image:
  name: my.private.registry.com/my-repository/ci-tools:latest

variables:
  TF_IN_AUTOMATION: "true"
  PLAN: "plan.tfplan"
  application_name: "my_app"
  
variables: &eu-variables
  TF_VAR_region: "westeurope"

variables: &us-variables
  TF_VAR_region: "eastus"

variables: &dev-variables
  TF_VAR_application_name: "$application_name"

stages:
  - Validate
  - Plan

dev-plan:
  variables:
    <<: *dev-variables
    <<: *eu-variables
  stage: Plan
  script:
    - echo "$PLAN"
    - echo "$TF_VAR_application_name"
    - echo "$application_name"
    
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - "$PLAN"
```

When the pipeline runs, `$PLAN`, `TF_VAR_application_name`, and `application_name` are blank and the output is as follows:

```
.....
$ echo "$PLAN"
$ echo "$application_name"
$ echo "$TF_VAR_application_name"
..........
```

What am I missing? Why is the job variable not able to see the global variable?

Answer (score 0):

By using global, just put all your variables in variables:

example

```
variables:
   TF_VAR_region_WE: "westeurope"
   TF_VAR_region_EU: "eastus"
   .....
```

also by reading the docs, its not recommend to use " <<: "

see this documentation https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#yaml-anchors-for-scripts